# How did maloc manage to grab the memory that was already allocated in SSL Heartbeat?

Tags: c, openssl

The recent Heartbleed vulnerability is caused by this particular unchecked execution:

```
buffer = OPENSSL_malloc(1 + 2 + payload + padding);
```

(according to http://java.dzone.com/articles/everything-you-need-know-about-2)

But how could malloc at any time grab the memory that is already dished out somewhere else. Even though `payload` and `padding` variables are filled out by the user values, but it seems to me that these would only be able to cause an out of memory error (with the very large value), and *not* the shift in address space in order to read the server's RAM outside of this very buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSL uses its own memory allocator (for speed reasons so they say). Therefore memory never gets passed back to the operation system. Instead they pool unused buffers and re-use them.

If you call OPENSSL_malloc the chances are almost 100% that the buffer you get contains data previously used by OpenSSL. This could be encrypted data, unencrypted data or even the private encryption keys.

Comment: So when allocation happens there is nothing to mark that portion of it 'allocated'?

Comment: It gets marked as allocated, but it still contains data from previous SSL usage.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.  It grabs a small block of memory and then proceeds to copy a much larger amount of data out of it, reading past the end of the malloc'd block into whatever happens to lie after it on the heap -- other malloc'd blocks (both alive and dead) that have been used for other things (other clients or system stuff) -- and copies that raw data to the attacker.